# Verifying data from xpath location having multiple data

Tags: karate

I have XML like below where I need to verify XML with lot of data with same names (index appended) 
like below.

I don't want to give separate column for each name,mobile etc. So in Example I am passing sum,men,1212121212,682312;suj,men,2212121212,682312**;**suu,men,3212121212,682312  OR I can pass in JSON format

```
1. What is the best way to do this without using Java Code. 
2. *def strVals=get response/Response/transaction/values 
    And print strVals 
 - Not printing any value 

 <Response>
       <RequestID>1</RequestID>
       <transaction>
          <values>
             <data name="firstName0">sum</data>
             <data name="lastName0">men</data>
             <data name="mobile0">1212121212</data>
             <data name="zip0">682312</data>
             <data name="firstName1">suj</data>
             <data name="lastName1">men</data>
             <data name="mobile1">2212121212</data>
             <data name="zip1">682312</data>
             <data name="firstName2">suu</data>
             <data name="lastName2">men</data>
             <data name="mobile2">3212121212</data>
             <data name="zip2">682312</data>
             <data name="firstName3">ssss</data>
             <data name="lastName3">mmmmmmm</data>
             <data name="mobile3">4212121212</data>
             <data name="zip3">682312</data>
          </values>
       </transaction>
    </Response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll provide a hint on how to dynamically build this XML, the rest is up to you:

```
* def temp = <values></values>
* def data = [{first: 'John', value: 'foo'}, {first: 'Smith', value: 'bar'}]
* def fun = 
"""
function(x, i){ 
  var path = '/values/data[' + (i + 1) + ']';
  karate.set('temp', path + '/@name', 'firstName' + i);
  karate.set('temp', path, x.value);
}
"""
* karate.forEach(data, fun)
* print temp
```

Which will result in:

```
<values>
  <data name="firstName0">foo</data>
  <data name="firstName1">bar</data>
</values>
```